# JavaScript: calling private method's property on class object

Tags: javascript

For the **class** **Engine**, "**start**" and "**stop**" are two `public methods` which internally calls "**ignitionOn**" and "**ignitionOff**".
   After "**start**" is called the `private method` sets a variable "`ignitionIndicator`" to "`true`" on the `engine instance` and "`stop`" sets it to "`false`".

However that is not happening. Something is going wrong since the "ignitionIndicator" value is always "undefined". I have to keeping the following in mind.

(i) Visibility of the methods should be as it is.

(ii) I CAN NOT set the variable directly from the `public methods`. The variable should be only and only set from within the `private method`.

```
function Engine() {
  function EngineConstructor() { };

  // publicly accessible methods
  EngineConstructor.prototype.start = function() {
    ignitionOn();
  };

  EngineConstructor.prototype.stop = function() {
    ignitionOff();
  };

  // private methods 
  function ignitionOn() {
    // does other things and sets this to true
    this.ignitionIndicator = true;
  };

  function ignitionOff() {
    // does other things and sets this to false
    this.ignitionIndicator = false;
  };

  return new EngineConstructor();  
};
var e = new Engine();
e.start();
e.ignitionIndicator // undefined, should have been true
e.stop();
e.ignitionIndicator // undefined, should have been false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to call those methods such that `this` refers to an instance, for instance via `Function#call` or `Function#apply`, e.g.:

```
EngineConstructor.prototype.start = function() {
    ignitionOn.call(this);
};
```

Or alternately, just pass the instance as an argument (procedural style):

```
EngineConstructor.prototype.start = function() {
    ignitionOn(this);
};

// ...

function ignitionOn(instance) {
    // does other things and sets this to true
    instance.ignitionIndicator = true;
}
```

---

The pattern you're using in that code is very odd. You have a function, `Engine`, which you use as a constructor (via `new`) but which **isn't** a constructor (it returns something other than the instance created by the `new` operator), and the object it returns is unrelated to the `Engine` function — instead, it's an instance created by `EngineConstructor`. Worse, it creates a whole new `EngineConstructor` every time you call it. This is hugely inefficient; if you want to recreate all the methods for every instance, you can do so much more simply.

But I'd just revisit the entire structure so that you **do** get method reuse. If the goal is to have a constructor function which has access to private methods from prototype methods, the revealing module pattern (applied here to a single constructor) is the usual way to do that:

```js
var Engine = function() {
    // The constructor
    function Engine() {
    }

    // Publicly accessible methods
    Engine.prototype.start = function() {
        ignitionOn.call(this);
    };

    Engine.prototype.stop = function() {
        ignitionOff.call(this);
    };

    // Private methods 
    function ignitionOn() {
        // does other things and sets this to true
        this.ignitionIndicator = true;
    }

    function ignitionOff() {
        // does other things and sets this to false
        this.ignitionIndicator = false;
    }

    return Engine;
}();
var e = new Engine();
e.start();
snippet.log(e.ignitionIndicator);
e.stop();
snippet.log(e.ignitionIndicator);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Function *declarations* don't have a `;` after them. `;` is a statement terminator, and function declarations (such as those for `ignitionOn` and `ignitionOff`) are not statements.